# Random, but should not exceed total

Tags: php, random, generator

```
rand(1,5)
```

.. generates random numbers for example: `4 3 2 3 2` (sum is equal 14).

I want the total to NOT exceed `x` (which is say 5), so in this case, it could be:

```
1 + 2 + 2 = 5
2 + 3 = 5
```

and so on ... variable length as long as `sum < x`

Should I generate a random, check against x, generate another, check again or is there another way?

Comment: Do you want to generate a set of fixed length or want a set of variable length as long as its `sum < x`? Also why are you doing this/are there more constraints? Currently I'd flag this as "primarily opinion based"/"too broad"

Comment: variable length as long as `sum < x`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most obvious way is just to keep looping and generating a smaller and smaller random number until you're capped out.

```
$min = 2;
$max = 5;
$randoms = [];
while ($max > $min) {
    $max -= ( $rand = rand($min, $max) );
    $randoms[] = $rand;
}
```

---

Updated for the actual use-case (see comments):

```
function generateRandomSpend($balance, $maximum = 5, $minimum = 2) {
    $amounts = array();

    while ($balance) {
        // If we can't add any more minimum-spends, stop
        if ($balance - $minimum < 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            // Don't generate pointlessly-high values
            $maximum = min($balance, $maximum);
            $balance -= $amounts[] = rand($minimum, $maximum);
        }
    }

    return $amounts;
}

print_r( $s = generateRandomSpend(10) );
```

You can also do

```
echo array_sum( generateRandomSpend(10) );
```

to get a numeric value of their total spend.

Answer (score 3):

This is also working and give result which you want

```
<?php
    $fixed = 5;
    $random = array();
    $no = 0;
    while(1) {
        $number = rand(1,5);
        $no +=$number; 
        if($no > $fixed) {
            break;
        }
        $random[]= $number;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: @joe In question it is specified that sum < 5 not eqauls to 5 so it is ok if it gives first no 3 , it will alone 3